# Attatch a bucket target location variable to an upload

Tags: fine-uploader

Forgive me for asking questions on behalf of my developer.

I need to define in the s3handler.php a variable called $targetbucket which is simply a amazon s3 bucket, not the one that is used to upload the files to but a subsequent bucket for user to encode video output into. This targetbucket is different for every user who uses the upload function and is used in a send email function inside the php file and includes relevant information pertaining to the next step in my process.

I am told the php file can't get this variable unless it's attached to the upload script. Ok- but this has to be a static script that I want for every user.
Therefore I need to define in my html a variable which is sent to the upload script and in turn to the php to use in the email function.

Is this at all possible? If not, what other method might I use please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why this variable needs to be passed from Fine Uploader. Regardless, you can pass any variable you like as a request parameter using Fine Uploader's [`setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams). For example, `uploader.setParams({targetBucket: 'some-bucket'})` will include a matching parameter for *all* file upload requests.

Comment: My setup was like this and I used target as the var uploader2.fineUploaderS3('setUploadSuccessParams',{target: target, userid: userid, useremail: useremail, filesize: file_size},id);